# importing modules in python with complex project structure

Tags: python, import

I am running into all sorts of import issues with my project. I have been looking though similar questions and am trying to put this all together.

My project has a layout similar the one shown below:

```
.
├── bar.py
├── data_processor.py
├── foo.py
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── processors
│   ├── bar_processor.py
│   ├── foo_processor.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── requirements.txt
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── test_data
│   │   ├── test_data_1.json
│   │   └── test_data_2.json
│   ├── test_foo.py
│   └── test_processor.py
└── utils
    ├── api.py
    ├── general.py
    └── __init__.py
```

I have been running into the following issues and would appreciate some guidance on how to resolve them.

1. Import python module from elsewhere for use in an **unit test**

As depicted in the project structure above, I have my unit tests inside a directory named 'tests'. In this example, I have two python files with tests, `test_foo.py` and `test_processor.py`. For `test_foo.py`, I need to import the following:

- foo.py
- bar.py
- utils/general.py
- utils/api.py

*What would my import statements need to be in order to do this?*

2. Import python modules from elsewhere for use in **regular module**

The second import scenario that has been giving me some trouble is when I need to import functionality from elsewhere in the project. For example, as part of `bar_processor.py`, I would need to import the following:

- processor.py
- bar.py
- utils/general.py

*What would my import statements need to be in order to do this?*

Some additional info

- I do not have a PYTHONPATH environment variable defined
- I am hoping to be able to run the python unit tests via the command line as well as through an IDE (PyCharm, in my case)
- The regular python files are executed from the command line as part of various cron jobs.